# Talend: troaclerow vs toracleinput

Tags: talend

It seems like both toracleinput and toracelrow can execute a select statement, can someone tell when to use toracleinput component, when to use toraclerow component in talend and what is the difference between them?

thanks
M

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The major difference between `toracleinput` and `toraclerow` is,

- In `toracleinput`, you can run only `SELECT` statement. Whereas in `toraclerow`, you can run any DDL and DML queries
- In `toracleinput`, you can have only one `SELECT` statement. Whereas in `toraclerow`, you can have multiple queries (If you are having select statement followed by delete or any other CRUD statement, then select will not return any resultset).
- **You can use `toracleinput`, when source DB and Target DB are different servers. But in `toraclerow`, the source and the Target should be the in the Same DB and same Server**

Consider the below tables

Employee Table:

```
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|   ID  |   Name    |   Salary  |   DeptId  |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|   1   |   Name1   |   10000   |   1       |
|   2   |   Name2   |   20000   |   2       |
|   3   |   Name3   |   30000   |   3       |
|   4   |   Name4   |   40000   |   1       |
|   5   |   Name5   |   50000   |   2       |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

Also consider table

Dept table

```
+-------+-----------+
|   ID  |   Name    |
+-------+-----------+
|   1   |   Dept1   |
|   2   |   Dept2   |
|   3   |   Dept3   |
+-------+-----------+
```

In talend, I wanted to select data and join these table and insert into another table named `dim_employee` which has below format

```
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
|   ID  |   Name    |   Salary  |   DeptId  | DeptName  |
+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

In Talend, I can do this in two ways,

1. Using input component,

[image]

2. Using Row Component

[image]

Using Row component, I can directly write the `INSERT INTO SELECT`.

**Note: When comparing the performance, using Row component is much faster than using Input component in this scenario.**